# Copy Apps and Data From Phone With Dead Screen

Tags: adb, data-recovery, broken-screen, data-transfer, scrcpy

My unrooted phone's LCD screen is dead but touchscreen still works. By using a series of stencils for where on-screen buttons and prompts would be, I am able to unlock the device and authorize ADB, though with considerable trial and error (~10 minutes to hit the "authorize" button). I am also able to use scrcpy to view the phone's screen.

However, I want to set up a new Android phone (different model and manufacturer), ideally using the "Copy apps & data" feature on the new phone. The problem with this is that even the "transfer over WiFi" feature seems not to work with the active ADB session needed for scrcpy.

My question is: what is the best way to transfer apps and data off of the old phone and onto the new one? I can get the files off fine, but I want app data, contacts, etc. I've looked over the methods others have suggested, and am unsure what would be the most reliable and efficient for my specific case. Would I be best served by one of the paid apps (install using scrcpy)? Reverse engineering the prompt locations for the wired transfer (no ADB needed)? Backing up via ADB (potentially more reliable)?

Comment: Depending on which Android version is running on the phone adb backup would be an option, however modern Android versions (AFAIR 12+) have more or less disabled adb backup and restore so on a new phone you may run into problems restoring the backup. Also a lot of apps don't allow adb backup. The way that should transfer the most data and apps is a direct USB connection. But I am not aware if this will work without screen.

Comment: I don't know how that transfer over wifi work, but if it uses your home wifi you could try adb over tcpip